# Modify Table of Contents Markup to show only Heading 4-5

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents, markup

I've seen [many posts](https://superuser.com/search?q=add%20level%20to%20table%20of%20contents%20word) on how to modify the markup of a Table of Contents in Word 2007+ to include additional Header levels, however I cannot set a custom range.

For example, if I insert a Table of Contents, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>, I see the following markup:

```
{TOC \o "1-3" \h \z \u}
```

If I try and change it to:

```
{TOC \o "4-5" \h \z \u}
```

Nothing changes.  Is this a limitation of the software, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Works for me (Word 2010). Have you updated TOC after this change?

Comment: Yes, but Headings 1-3 still appear, and nothing for Headings 4-5.  Let me try in a different document and see if it's just this one I am working in.

Answer (score 0):

I copied everything over to a new Word Document and once I did the TOC updated and only showed Headings 4-5.  Strange that it would not update in the original.  As noted by @endrju - updating the TOC is also a good thing to do once the markup has been altered.